# Monkey-patching the Time class in Rails leads to time zone confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got a Rails 3.2.6 app running on Ruby 1.8.7. The app is configured to use central European time (i.e. UTC+2) as its time zone, and in my initializers, I monkey-patch `Time` and `DateTime` with some custom functionality.

The odd thing is, that in my monkey-patched methods, the Time/DateTime instances act as if they're UTC (but using the time zone-adjusted value), but elsewhere in the app they respect the time zone config.

So, as an example, in `config/initializers/monkey_patching.rb` I have the following

```
module MonkeyPatching
  def foo
    inspect
  end
end

class Time
  include MonkeyPatching
end

class DateTime
  include MonkeyPatching
end
```

Now, elsewhere in the app (or in the rails console), here's what I get

```
model.created_at.inspect #=> "Mon, 24 Sep 2012 15:06:34 CEST +02:00" (correct!)
model.created_at.foo     #=> "Mon Sep 24 15:06:34 UTC 2012"          (all wrong!)
```

So, calling `inspect` "directly" on `model.created_at` gives me the correct, timezone-adjusted result. But calling the patched-in method `foo` - which also just calls `inspect`! - treats the time as UTC, even though it isn't.

To add to my confusion, this only happens with model attributes. I.e. in the rails console, I get identical - and correct - results for `DateTime.now.inspect` and for `DateTime.now.foo`. But doing the same for a DateTime attribute, give me the strange behavior seen above.

Any idea why this happens (and how to fix it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails uses `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` for time attributes, not regular Ruby `Time`. Try to patch `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` too.

```
class ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
  include MonkeyPatching
end
```

Comment: Ah, of course! That was it - thanks! The app I'm dealing with uses a lot of "raw" Time/Date instances in its business logic, so I completely forgot about TimeWithZone